# 3D secure authentication and Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I am creating subscriptions upon completing the Stripe Checkout session and from what I have read, stripe supports 3d secure authentication payment on its checkout session. However, if this is true for the first time the client pays for the subscription (stripe will ask him to enter a code on the checkout session page), how will that be applicable for the remaining payments in the following months? Where will the user enter the code?

Comment: See [Stripe's docs](https://support.stripe.com/questions/strong-customer-authentication-sca-exemptions-for-recurring-charges-with-stripe-billing) covering this topic. The short explanation is that recurring charges will request exemptions and if 3DS is still required, Stripe will email the user to perform it (you can modify that behavior in your Dashboard settings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Stripe Billing, your user will be automatically charged on recurring months. So they usually only have to complete 3DS for the initial payment. But if the card issuer requires 3DS to be fulfilled every invoice, you can configure your Stripe settings to automatically email your user to complete 3DS on a Stripe hosted page. However, if you want to write custom failure handling, you will need to add a webhook for customer.subscription.updated and check if the status is past_due.
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/overview#recurring-charges

Comment: Thank You so much ! You mentioned first : "assuming you are using stripe billing" , can you please tell me what does that mean to check if that's my case. Just a quick reminder the payment occurs on my website using the Stripe 's own Checkout Page in case that's what you mean by Stripe Billing.

Comment: And just another question if I want to check for the past_due status of a subscription, should I pay attention to the fact that this status is also present in the case of a payment failed event?

Comment: If you're using Stripe Checkout, it applies to your case too. Stripe Billing is just an example, especially if you're implementing your own backend logic to handle recurring payments. https://stripe.com/docs/billing

Comment: You're right, if payment failed for an invoice then the status will be in `past_due` state. But if you're not handling the logic on your side, you can configure some settings in Stripe to automatically send an email to your user to complete 3DS on Stripe's hosted link. But if you're handling the logic, you have to listen to the webhook `customer.subscription.updated` event, and some APIs like https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/send should be useful.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Just added off_session when you create charge about user.

```
$user->charge($price, $paymentMethod, ['off_session' => true]);
```

Hopefully, it would be worked for you.